# In Scala, can generic type parameters be used with *function* definitions?

Tags: scala, generics

Is there a syntax to allow generic type parameters on function literals? I know I could wrap it in a method such as:

```
def createLongStringFunction[T](): (T) => Boolean = {
  (obj: T) => obj.toString.length > 7
}
```

but then I end up needing to invoke the method for every type T and getting a new function. I looked through the language reference, and while I see that the function literal syntax is translated by the compiler to an instance of a *Functionn* object that itself has generic input types, it looks like the compiler magic realizes those parameters at the time of creation. I haven't found any syntax that allows me to, in effect, "leave one or more of the type parameters of *Functionn* unbound". What I would prefer is something along the lines of:

```
// doesn't compile
val longStringFunction: [T](T) => Boolean = (obj: T) => obj.toString.length > 7
```

Does any such thing exist? Or for that matter, what is the explicit type of an eta-expansion function when the method being expanded has generic parameters?

This is a purely contrived and useless example. Of course I could just make the function use Any here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, type parameters only apply to methods and not function objects. For example,

```
def f[T](x: T) = x     //> f: [T](x: T)T
val g = f _            //> g: Nothing => Nothing = <function1>
// g(2)                // error
val h: Int=>Int = f _  //> h  : Int => Int = <function2>
h(2)                   //> res0: Int = 2
```

The method `f` cannot be converted to a polymorphic function object `g`. As you can see, the inferred type of `g` is actually `Function1[Nothing, Nothing]`, which is useless. However, with a type hint we can construct `h: Function1[Int,Int]` that works as expected for `Int` argument.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that might be the case. Expanding the method this way does open the door for the more complex cases, though. While I can't find a way to do it without the intermediate method, the type hint on assignment can carry this surprisingly far, such as:
`def doStuff[T, U](moreStuff: T => U)(obj: T) = moreStuff(obj)
val timeAndAHalf = doStuff[Int, Double](_ * 1.5) _`

which chops quite a bit from its explicit counterpart
`def doStuff[T, U](moreStuff: T => U)(obj: T): U = moreStuff(obj)
val timeAndAHalf: Int => Double = (num: Int) => doStuff[Int, Double](num => num * 1.5)(num)`

Comment: What is the reason that type parameters are not applicable to function objects?

Comment: @PaulCarey check this out http://milessabin.com/blog/2012/04/27/shapeless-polymorphic-function-values-1/

Answer (score 8):

As you say, in your example all you're requiring is the `toString` method and so `Any` would be the usual solution. However, there is call for being able to use higher-rank types in situations such as applying a type constructor such as `List` to every element in a tuple.

As the other answers have mentioned, there's no direct support for this, but there's a relatively nice way to encode it:

```
trait ~>[A[_],B[_]] {
  def apply[X](a : A[X]) : B[X]
}

type Id[A] = A //necessary hack

object newList extends (Id ~> List) {
  def apply[X](a : Id[X]) = List(a)
}

def tupleize[A,B, F[_]](f : Id ~> F, a : A, b : B) = (f(a), f(b))

tupleize(newList, 1, "Hello") // (List(1), List(Hello))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `longStringFunction` defined as followed is a **value**, which must have some **given type**.

```
val longStringFunction: (T) => Boolean = (obj: T) => obj.toString.length > 7
```

However, you can reuse a function object with a method:

```
scala> val funObj: Any => Boolean = _.toString.size > 7
funObj: Any => Boolean = <function1>

scala> def typedFunction[T]: T => Boolean = funObj
typedFunction: [T]=> T => Boolean

scala> val f1 = typedFunction[String]
f1: String => Boolean = <function1>

scala> val f2 = typedFunction[Int]
f2: Int => Boolean = <function1>

scala> f1 eq f2
res0: Boolean = true
```

This works because `trait Function1[-T1, +R]` is **contravariant** of type `T1`.

Comment: Ah true. This is effectively just casting to a more constrained type. We could, in fact, forego the method altogether and simply assign the function e.g.
`val f1: String => Boolean = funObj`

Answer (score 1):

In scala, Function values are parametrically monomorphic(while methods are polymorphic)

Shapeless library introduces polymorphic function values  which may be mapped over HLists and many more other features.

Please consider the following refs:
http://www.chuusai.com/2012/04/27/shapeless-polymorphic-function-values-1/
http://www.chuusai.com/2012/05/10/shapeless-polymorphic-function-values-2/

Comment: This is not true for Scala 3 anymore, Scala 3 introduced polymorphic functions to the language: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/polymorphic-function-types.html