# Problems with covariant parameters last in curried method

Tags: scala, currying, variance

This is starting to be a pretty common situation for me:

```
  trait CoVariant[+T] {
    def bar: T
  }

  def curried[T](x: String)(y: CoVariant[T]) = y // Not really, but for simplicity
  val applied = curried("foo") _

  val bar = new CoVariant[String] {
    def bar = "bar"
  }
  applied(bar)
```

So I have something that's co-variant and I need to do some common stuff first and then have a generic part left unapplied. I would really like to be able to write it just like a curried function like above, but that of course yields a compile error on the last line:

```
- type mismatch;  found   : CoVariant[String]  required: CoVariant[Nothing]
```

I seem to resort to just introducing a class just to have someplace to stick the type parameter so it can be left abstract:

```
trait StupidWrapper {
   def apply[T](y: CoVariant[T]) : CoVariant[T]
}
```

and instead of the curried thing have

```
def notAsNice(x: String) = new StupidWrapper {
   def apply[T](y: CoVariant[T]) = y
}
```

so now:

```
val applied = notAsNice("foo")
applied(bar)
```

compiles.

This feels stupid and I guess there is better ways?

**Update:**

I think I'll better concretize. What I have is this:

```
  abstract class ParserToSeq {
    def apply[T](parser: Parser[T]): Seq[T]
  }

  def fromTrainingData(trainingLines: Seq[String]) = new ParserToSeq {
    def apply[T](p: Parser[T]) = trainingLines.map(parseAll(p, _)).map {
      _ match {
        case Success(wt, _) => Some(wt)
        case _ => None
      }
    }.flatten
  }
```

and then

```
val thisData = fromTrainingData(trainingLines)
lazy val wordTags = thisData(wordtagParser) // Parser[WordTag]
lazy val uniGrams = thisData(uniGramParser) // Parser[UniGram]
…
```

I just want to do away with the ParserToSeq and do:

```
def fromTrainingData[T](trainingLines: Seq[String])(p: Parser[T]) = 
  trainingLines.map(parseAll(p, _)).map {
  _ match {
    case Success(wt, _) => Some(wt)
    case _ => None
  }
}.flatten
```

Note that the T here is specific for each parser. The problem as I understand it that the T is resolved to a concrete type on the partially applied method even though the type actually applies to the second parameter list.

It seems I would like to kindof stick the declaration of the type param somewhere in the middle:

```
def fromTrainingData(trainingLines: Seq[String])[T](p: Parser[T])
```

which of course isn't valid Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention, scala `Function` objects [don't carry type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15264993/500314).

However, you can replace `ParseToSeq` with a [more generic `~>` that takes higher-kinded types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15268017/500314),

```
trait ~>[A[_],B[_]] {
  def apply[X](a : A[X]) : B[X]
}
```

Then your example becomes,

```
trait Parser[T]
trait WordTag
trait UniGram
val trainingLines: Seq[String] = ???
val wordtagParser: Parser[WordTag] = ???
val uniGramParser: Parser[UniGram] = ???

def fromTrainingData[T](trainingLines: Seq[String]) = new ~>[Parser,Seq] {
  def apply[T](p: Parser[T]): Seq[T] = ???
}
val thisData = fromTrainingData(trainingLines)
lazy val wordTags = thisData(wordtagParser) // Seq[WordTag]
lazy val uniGrams = thisData(uniGramParser) // Seq[UniGram]
```

Comment: Cool! Yeah, I kind of understood the technical limitations, but the pattern seems so common there should be some standard thingy like the one you propose. Is there something like this in say scalaz?

Comment: I'm not familiar with scalaz; I'd also like to know if it has this.

Comment: Jep, scalaz had it: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.0.0-RC2/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/NaturalTransformation.scala